# Is recurrent policy used defaultly in OpenAI's A2C baseline?

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

For atari games, is "recurrent policy" used defaultly in A2C? I found it's hard to understand their highly-engineered code.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean whether they are using a recurrent neural network by default in A2C? If so, the answer is no. They are using CNN from the nature paper by default. It is a little complicated to follow but this [blog post](https://danieltakeshi.github.io/2018/09/27/openai-baselines-refactored/) does a good job at explaining the code.